# Utilizing Objects like SVMDataGenerator in Spark Shell/Scala Code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a bit new to spark and I was wondering how to use objects like SVMDataGenerator, described in the API Doc here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.util.SVMDataGenerator$

Specifically, I was having trouble with actually having them work in the Spark shell or in code that I have created in .scala files and then compiled with sbt. In the Spark shell, I tried something like:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util._
SVMDataGenerator("local", <filepath>)
```

This, however, throws an error, as it claims that SVMDataGenerator does not accept parameters. I did something similar in a scala file, and again an error was thrown. Looking at the source code for the object, however, I can see that it accepts arguments. I'm just kind of lost on how I would actually use this object (and other similar objects), and any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the source code, [SVMDataGenerato](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/SVMDataGenerator.scala)r is an executable object. That is, it contains a `main(String[])` method meant to be executed. eg. from a  command line like:

```
$>scala -cp sparkmllib.jar org.apache.spark.mllib.util.SVMDataGenerator <master> <output_dir> [num_examples] [num_features] [num_partitions]
```

If you would like to execute it programmatically, you could do something like:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util._
SVMDataGenerator.main(Array("<master>", "<output_dir>", "[num_examples]", "[num_features]", "[num_partitions]")
```

(replace parameters as necessary)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize I had to put SVMDataGenerator.main